# Virtual COM port to Socket communication

Tags: c++, c, sockets, serial-port, windows-ce

I have a virtual COM port and socket in my app , i want to transfer data from this Virtual COM port to a socket and vice versa.
How can i do this?

Is there some sample code or good library out there to do so? Eventually this should work on Windows CE, but initially it should work on regular Windows.

Comment: I am using VisualC++ and the data i usually would get to and from the Virtual COM port is binary data.

Comment: I have found some options like ser2net and http://docwiki.gumstix.org/index.php/Sample_code/C/Serial_Daemon. But both seems to be tied to Linux platform. I am looking to have something for Windows platform

Comment: I did not implement some kind of "serial to socket service" myself. I used a network-based com port sharing app to "provide serial com port sharing over my local area ethernet". Would that work in your case?  http://www.eltima.com/products/serialshare/

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for some source code. The ultimate aim would be to port that code on winCE 5.0 or WinCE6.0 because my app will work on WinCE

Comment: I think in that case, you're 100% on your own. There is very little library code that will recompile cleanly and run on CE.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you need the service to do.
Is it bi-directional, does opening the port have to automatically setup a new network link, do you need to set serial port parameters over the network?

If you only really need to remote a serial port and don't need any command and control data then most introductions to network programming start with some sort of chat server where everything typed at the client end goes to the server as text - it should be trivial to modify this so that the source text comes from a serial port

Comment: Good point.  while not terminated: get char, put char. repeat.